# Defining large constant arrays in solidity

Tags: solidity

I want to define a large array, hardcoded into the smart contract. I know there's not currently a way to define a constant array in a smart contract and there has to be a getter function implemented, as e.g.

```
function get_S() public pure returns (uint256[] memory) {
  uint256[285] memory Sf = [
    7511745149465107256748700652201246547602992235352608707588321460060273774987,
    1781874611967874592137274483616240894881315449294815307306613366069350853425,
    9676220459425127104563807626505378474104527268335041816433595157913150665495,
    ...
    9131299761947733513298312097611845208338517739621853568979632113419485819303
  ];
  uint256[] memory Sd = new uint256[](285);
  for (uint256 i = 0; i < 285; i++) {
    Sd[i] = Sf[i];
  }
  return Sd;
}
```

But this makes contract deployment produce

```shell
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="Transaction reverted: trying to deploy a contract whose code is too large", method="estimateGas"
```

I can solve this by making the contract store my constants in the constructor (so I have to pass them to the constructor at deployment), but I'd like it better if that was not necessary. Is there a way of solving this nicely?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a constant array as a static array with fixed length and initializing it. Anyways, according to EIP-170, the proposal specifies that the deployment of a contract whose bytecode is more than 24 kb should fail. You may need to downsize your code.

See:

https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-170

https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/downsizing-contracts-to-fight-the-contract-size-limit/